# How to convert date (html datetime-local tag) to a SQL Server datetime?

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server

I'm developing web site in ASP and need to insert datetime into SQL Server from a datetime-local tag (html).

ASP server reads date from datetime-local tag and insert it into SQL Server as a datetime

```
input type="datetime-local" name="time"    // html

getRequest("time", REQUEST_POST)           // asp

insert into table values(time);            // SQL Server (data type : datetime)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`FORMAT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function, which is supported from MSSQL Server 2012 version:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES(FORMAT(TIME, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'))
```

Comment: `FORMAT()` Supported after SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
INSERT INTO SampleTABLE(dateColumn) VALUES(CONVERT(DATETIME,'18-06-12 10:34:09 PM',5))
```